# Increasing the WYSIWYG-ness of Emacs

Tags: emacs

I have a question in need of an Emacs expert, perhaps someone who is knowledgeable additionally in HTML/LaTeX, but someone who is primarily an emacs expert.

While writing files to typeset documents (in HTML, LaTeX, ..) I would like to make sure that I am including the right images, in HTML whenever I use `<img ...>` and in LaTeX whenever I use `\includegraphics{...}`.

Is there a way to include an image within the emacs buffer, either automatically or when I hover over the tag/command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the inline image mode:

https://github.com/Wilfred/remacs/blob/master/lisp/iimage.el

If you are doing a lot of TeXing, AUCTeX is awesome. However, for a little less syntax-heavy option, you can learn org-mode and then export to latex.

- http://orgmode.org/
- http://orgmode.org/manual/LaTeX_002fPDF-export-commands.html
- http://floatsolutions.com/blog/2010/10/displaying-inline-images-in-emacs-org-mode/

I think that the org-mode + inline image + LaTeX export (a native feature of org-mode) will be the best way to go. Org-mode is quite easy to learn, extremely well supported, has a great community, and the LaTeX export works really well. Then, you can just tweak the latex that org-mode generates, but the org-mode export will do 99% of the work, effectively making it WYSIWYG for images, tables, etc.

Comment: Um.. what is there to export? So orgmode requires one to write a .org file to be able to parse a .tex file? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: No, you write a document in org-mode and then you can translate that document to a tex file, which gets parsed and rendered with `latex`, `pdflatex`, `xelatex`, etc. Some people who don't like writing in tex itself find writing in org mode more comfortable, and then you can have org mode make a tex document that looks pretty good. See this blog post: http://www.mfasold.net/blog/2009/02/using-emacs-org-mode-to-draft-papers/

Comment: Interesting idea, but that means learning yet a third typesetting syntax. To produce both html and latex, I have in the past used latex2html on a latex file. The output can then be fine-tuned by hand. It's not (or at least was not) perfect, but it worked.

Comment: Well, if you want to stick with just tex, maybe use whizzytex. http://gallium.inria.fr/whizzytex/ I have used it before and its pretty good, although I tend to not use it.

Comment: @Calaf: org-mode is another way to have one syntax that generates multiple outputs -- it has an HTML export natively, as well (then again, it also has lots of other features that you might find useful within emacs: TODO items, etc. etc.).  If you already know LaTeX, and want to stick with it, fine.  Just hoping to make sure you understand why the suggestion was made.

Comment: image-mode works very well. It may not have been ready 5 1/2 years ago, but now it is.

Answer (score 3):

For LaTex, you can use the AUCTeX package. After you install it you can toggle image previews with `C-c C-p C-p`.

More information about AUCTeX is available at:

http://www.gnu.org/s/auctex/

The preview mode is called `preview-latex`, User's Manual is located here:

http://www.gnu.org/s/auctex/manual/preview-latex.index.html

Comment: Adding
`(load "auctex.el" nil t t)`
`(load "preview-latex.el" nil t t)`
to my .emacs (as mentioned in the manual), loading a .tex file, and pressing `C-c C-p C-p` doesn't work. Any suggestions for the seed recipe to get started on this (apparently powerful but monstrous) package?

Comment: Is Emacs completely unresponsive when you do `C-C C-p C-p` or does something happen, like any change in the buffer or do you see an error message? Also, does preview-environment or preview-region work?

Comment: With my .emacs containing only:
`(setenv "PATH" (concat ".:/usr/texbin:/opt/local/bin"))
(add-to-list 'load-path "/usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp")
(require 'tex-site)
(load "auctex.el" nil t t)
(load "preview-latex.el" nil t t)
`
I get
`DviPS sentinel: Searching for program: no such file or directory, gs`
even though `gs` is indeed in `/opt/local/bin`.